# Cypress assertion fails with regex for contains method

Tags: regex, cypress

I have troubles asserting button text in Cypress with RegEx (I need an exact match).

**HTML**

```html
<button data-test-key="forward-button">Nexto</button>
```

**JS**

```js
const forwardButtonText = 'Nexto';

cy.find('button[data-test-key=forward-button]')
  .should(
    'contain',
    new RegExp(`^${forwardButtonText}$`, 'gi'),
    );
```

I followed this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57894080/8754822), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm getting an `AssertionError`.

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<button>' to contain /^Nexto$/gi
```

When I put the string `Nexto` manually, it passes.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Contain doesn't support regex, why not use match?

Comment: [`.should('contain'`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_include) (**not** the same thing as `.contains`) doesn't support regex, why not use [`'match'`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs [Assertions - Chai](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Chai)

> include(value) Aliases: **contain**, includes, contains
> expect([1,2,3]).to.include(2)

(more details in chai docs under `include` [here](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/)).

When used as `.should('contain', ...)` it is for array or object inclusion, but not string inclusion.

One way to exactly match the text is to extract it from the element and use `eq`,

```js
const forwardButtonText = 'Nexto';

cy.get('button[data-test-key=forward-button]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then(text => text.toLowerCase())
  .should('eq', forwardButtonText.toLowerCase())
```

or using Cypress `.contains()` as mentioned in comments

```js
cy.get('button[data-test-key=forward-button]')
  .contains(new RegExp(`^${forwardButtonText}$`, 'gi'))
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I need it to accept variable and be case insensitive. Is there a way to do this with you solutions?

Comment: Yes, with an additional line to get case insensitive matching.